# How to search the entire forest without using global catalog?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, openldap

I want to search the entire forest without Global Catalog because the GC doesn't have specific attributes that i am looking for. My question is , is it enough to search the entire forest, if i have the forest name(First Domain Controller name)?

Comment: Please share any code that you've tried so we can see how to help.

Comment: @LudovicPoitou I don't have a code. i just want to know if i can search through the forest without using gc?

Comment: You have 2 options here: add required attributes to gc by changing ad schema or make search in every forest domain